# has Jquery Datatable drawcomplete event?

Tags: datatables

DataTable has draw.dt event. But I need "**draw complete**" event. After rendering datatable, I would like to manipulate datatable's dom. I would like to wrap that event with Deferred Obj and return a promise.

Comment: Cant you use [initComplete](https://datatables.net/reference/option/initComplete) ??

Answer (score 0):

I understand Draw event fire after jquery datatable draw method. Actual probelm is, everytime draw, datatable reset all of the state info and refresh as I initialized it. So, I need to save state as object at memory. At draw event handler, get back state info and manipulate DOM which DataTable hold.